# Write .htaccess file to prevent cache in folder and subfolders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching, header

I want to edit my .htaccess to prevent the current folder plus all subfolders to cache content. The site contains html, images, swf, xml files.

I tried this, but the server did not like that.

```
<FilesMatch ".(js|css|pdf|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control no-cache
</FilesMatch>
```

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, xxx@xxx.com and inform them
>   of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that
>   may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>
> Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at www.xxx.com Port 80

Any tips?

Comment: Remember that `.` in regex is equal to all characters and not a dot. Use `\.` for a dot. This has nothing to do with your question; it's just an obvservation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request'

it looks like it has nothing to do with the code snippet above. Look in your VirtualHosts configuration. If you define a reference to a location in a DocumentRoot directive that doesn't exist, then Apache will throw an error.

Comment: That's the "additionally" part, original request also returned a 500.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is correct so my immediate Q is: have you got mod_headers enabled?

```
ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/headers.* -l
```

It usually is enabled but not always.  If not, then ask your admin to add the symlink.